# Remove Mask branch from Maskrcnn

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, mask, image-segmentation, faster-rcnn

is there anyway to disable the mask branch in both training and inference. I could use faster RCNN, but I have my code and annotation formats all up and running in Maskrcnn. So was just trying to figure out a quick way to remove the mask branch as I really need to increase the inference speed.
P.S. I am using Matterport MaskRCNN.

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate the load_mask() function.